# Roots of Unity Sum Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vectors, roots-of-unity

If $1,\omega,\omega^2,...\omega^{n-1}$ are complex numbers such that $\omega^n-1=0$, then

- they are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity
- they lie on the vertices of a regular polygon on the unit circle with center at the origin

For $n\geq2,$ $1+\omega+\omega^2+...+\omega^{n-1}=0$ can be proved using:

- Consider the LHS as a geometric series, and use the formula for the sum of that.
- Use vector addition to the equally spaced vertices, and note that their sum is invariant under rotation, and hence their sum is the zero vector.

**Consider a third  proof:**
Since it is a regular polygon with centroid at the origin:

- the sides are congruent
- when we consider the sides as position vectors they have angle $\theta, 2\theta, ...,n\theta.$
  Hence, they also form a set of vectors that are the position vectors of a regular polygon, and in the second proof above, we showed that they add up to zero.
  So this reduces to the second case, and is now proved.

Is this correct?

Edit: Added that the polygon has centroid at the origin based on yoyo's answer.

Comment: "*Hence they also form a set of vectors that add up to zero*" $\;-\;$ That is true, but it is not obvious/trivial enough that you can just state it without any proof or justification.

Comment: @dxiv correct. I added a justification connecting it to the second proof.

Comment: You could also prove it geometrically, on its own. Another direct proof comes from [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 1):

The oriented edges of any polygon will sum to zero (as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or complex numbers).  This says nothing about the sum of the vertices (as complex numbers).

For instance, the points
$$
\{0, 1, 1+i, i,\}
$$
sum to $2+2i$ but the edges
$$
\{1-0, 1+i-1, i-(1+i), 0-i\}=\{1,i,-1,-i\}
$$
sum to $0$.

---

[A square is a regular polygon; I don' know what a "cyclic" polygon is (the four vertices lie on a circle).  In any case, your "third proof" doesn't make sense to me, although after your edits, it seems you're saying that the oriented edges, translated and thought of as vertices, reproduce the same geometric figure (the roots of unity polygon).]

Comment: It's a regular polygon, not just cyclic.

Comment: You have missed the "cyclic" part. Cyclic or concyclic means a polygon  that lies on a circle https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points

Comment: Further, the centroid of the polygon we are considering is the origin. You have taken a polygon that is general, and hence does not give the answer we are looking for

Comment: You gave some statement, asked if it was correct, and I pointed out what I saw as a flaw.  Was that not the point of your question?

Comment: You were correct in pointing out the flaw. After giving it some thought, I have added that the regular polygon has centroid at the origin. Do let me know if this version is now correct.